# Base 2 logarithm in F#

Tags: f#

The F# language has the functions log which computes the natural logarithm and log10 which computes the base 10 logarithm.

What is the best way to compute a base 2 logarithm in F#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use the fact that the "a-logarithm of b" = ln(b) / ln(a), that is, the 2-logarithm of x is ln(x) / ln(2).

```
log2(8)  = ln(8)  / ln(2) = 3
log2(32) = ln(32) / ln(2) = 5
```

...where `ln` is either the natural logarithm or log10, either logarithm will work.

Comment: I wish I could accept both yours and Gustavo's answers as they both work. I am picking this answer however as it relies only on the routines from FSharp.Core (in FSharp.Core.dll) while Gustavo's introduces a dependency on System and and a possibly alternative definition of the logarithm.

Comment: @JonnyBoats No worries, but what do you mean with "dependency on System"? Can you not depend on it?

Comment: Gustavo, for whatever reason the f# language team chose to implement the logarithm functions in FSharp.Core.dll rather than use the standard .Net ones in System (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353819.aspx). I don't know why, and perhaps the code is identical for all I know. Since f# is an open language, the possibility exists that someone might do a different implementation on some operating system (like Mono).

Comment: @JonnyBoats They did so in order to provide ready to use functions (instead of methods) which are polymorphic over some types, the Math methods achieve the same through overloads, but there are some methods (like Log) which have different overloads (not just different types) so in some cases you have to call the Math methods with the desired overload. Regarding the dependency you can implement F# on a different OS, but it doesn't mean you will have to change the public interface of the System namespace.

Answer (score 10):

Use `System.Math.Log(number, base)`

Example:

```
open System
Math.Log(32., 2.)
val it : float = 5.0
```

Comment: +1 that is - of course - even easier than my solution. Didn't know of that function :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, in fact the MS inplementation of Log(double, double) does exactly what you said in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET 5.0 there is [`Math.Log2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.log2?view=net-6.0).

```ml
> Math.Log2 64;;
6
```